# In IE9 and IE9 Platform Preview, I am no longer able to call a Javascript method from my Java Applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet, internet-explorer-9

In prior versions of IE and in Firefox, I am able to call methodFoo in JavaScript from my Java Applet running on the same page.  In IE9, this no longer works.  Is there some additional step, or a different way of doing this that will work for IE9?

My Java Applet contains

```
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;
...
private transient JSObject jso;
...
public void init() {
    ...
    jso = JSObject.getWindow(this);
    ... }

public void CalledFromSecondaryThread(){
    ...
    jso.call("methodFoo", object_to_pass);
    ... }
```

My Html page contains

```
...
<object style="height: 1px;width: 650px;" classid = "clsid:CAFEEFAC-0016-0000-0011-ABCDEFFEDCBA" codebase = "http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6u11-windows-i586.cab#Version=6,0,0,11" id="AppletControl">
  <param name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx256m" />
  <param name = "CODE" value = "com.namespace.Applet.class" />
  <param name = "archive" value = "./lib/applet.jar" />
  <param name = "type" value = "application/x-java-applet;version=1.6" />
  <param name = "scriptable" value="true" />
  <param name = "mayscript" value="true" />
</object>
...
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/script.js"></script>
...
```

and script.js contains

```
function methodFoo(object_to_pass){     
    //doStuff
}
```

The Exception received from jso.call is

```
netscape.javascript.JSException: No such method "methodFoo" on JavaScript object
```

Comment: I have found that this also works in "Quirks" mode of IE9, so enabling quirks mode for the page is a reasonable workaround for some.

Comment: If you have (or create) a login for the Microsoft feedback portal, you can view the status of the bug here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/620646/calls-to-javascript-method-from-a-java-applet-are-failing-with-a-no-such-method-error

Comment: Have you tried with eval instead? Like `jso.eval("methodFoo()")`. When I use LiveConnect I don't use `call` at all since it's broken in FF Mac, Safari, and Opera 9.8. For more look at [information about liveconnect and deployment](http://www.cabo.dk/blog/jakobs-blog/applets-missing-information-about-liveconnect-and-deployment). By the way you link doesn't work. Is it fixed now?

Answer (score 1):

This was bug 620646 in IE 9 Beta - and has been fixed in the RC and newer versions of IE9
[Bug Report at Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/620646/calls-to-javascript-method-from-a-java-applet-are-failing-with-a-no-such-method-error)